# Bitnami LAMP stack .htmaccess not working

Tags: lamp, bitnami

I'm trying to migrate my website into a Bitnami LAMP standard stack in Google Cloud Platform.
In my old Apache server I use .htaccess with the command:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

If I don't have that file .htaccess the website does not work well.
When I copy the .htaccess file into /htdocs the website stop working
Any clue about how Bitnami works with .htaccess ?
(I have several days trying to find the solution)

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

I do not know the Bitnami LAMP version you are using and if you deployed your custom application in the /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs folder or in any other one but we suggest you check the Apache's configuration files (depending on the LAMP version and how you deployed the app: /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/*, /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts/* or /opt/bitnami/apps/yourcustomapp/conf/*) and see if the "AllowOverride" parameter is set to "All".

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Once you confirm that, please ensure you are accessing those files when browsing your site. And finally, please take a look at this guide in our documentation where we explain how to move the .htaccess information to an Apache's conf file to improve the security and the performance of the site.

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/lamp/administration/use-htaccess/

The guide basically explains how to move the .htaccess info to a htaccess.conf file in which you can set the same rules

```
<Directory "your/htdocs/folder">
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
</Directory>
```

Include it inside the Apache's conf folder

```
Include "path/to/the/htaccess.conf"
```

and restart Apache

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```